# adding two folder in one parent folder in one repository github

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have two folder which have two individual projects but inter-related to each other and both folder are in parent folder folder structure is as below

```
BBYN
|__external
|__spfx
```

I am trying to add git in BBYN folder but it is not adding. Help me to solve the issue
[image]

Comment: why do you use a screen shot instead of just the text of the terminal, and also most of the image is  junk and a partial view of the window behind. Transparent terminals really hinders reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you're getting is because you are trying to make an initial **push to the remote repository without having a valid git `commit`**.

You ran the command `git commit -m "Initial commit"`, **without adding the files to the staging area** by using `git add`, and hence there was no git commit made.

You need to first add your files to the staging area by

```
git add external spfx
```

which would add all the files within those 2 directories to the staging area for the commit, or you can select the required files separately using the same `git add` command (or `git add -A`, which would add all the files in the directory to the staging area for the commit).

Then run `git commit -m "Commit message"` and then `git push origin master` to push the changes to the remote repository.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much for the solution